# cakephp shell is not available

Tags: shell, cakephp

I am experienced in php, but new to cake and having some trouble, I did read through quite a bit on this before posting, so I do apologize if I am asking a very basic question as I feel like it has been answered, however maybe my lack of understanding for cakephp is holding me up.

I have a file 'convert.php' with the following code it it

```
<?php
class ConvertShell extends Shell {
    function main() {
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
        $this->out("Testing - ".$time."\n");
    }
} 
?>
```

This file is in '/home/photo/public_html/vendors/shells/convert.php'

when I run 'cake convert' I get the following:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v1.2.4 Console

Current Paths:
-app: photo
-working: /home/photo
-root: /home
-core: /usr/share/php


Available Shells:
    acl
    api
    bake
    console
    i18n
    schema
    testsuite
```

I have seen a number of solutions pointing to the fact that I should have the shell file in '/home/photo/app/vendors/shells' instead, however I don't have an app folder.  There is a log of cakephp code already running and working correctly, so cake is running fine as far as I know.

Comment: The issue was I was not set up as a production setup of cakephp, so you have to use the core setup. So the app folder is located in the cake folder, not in your webroot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was not set up as a production setup of cakephp, so you have to use the core setup. So the app folder is located in the cake folder, not in your webroot.